# discord.js Buttons to accept an request

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButtons } = require('discord.js')
```

```js
const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('accept')
                    .setLabel('Aceitar')
                    .setStyle('SUCESS')
            )
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('deny')
                    .setLabel('Recusar')
                    .setStyle('DANGER')
            )
        interaction.reply({ content: `a`, components: [row] })
```

I wan't to make the bot reply with two buttons to people accept and it's getting this error

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
data.components[0].components[0].style: This field is required
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper success style is `SUCCESS`, not `SUCESS`. Changing that should result in a valid message component:

```js
const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('accept')
                    .setLabel('Aceitar')
                    .setStyle('SUCCESS')
            )
...
```